# If $A$ is skew-symmetric, then a fixed row/column operation produces a new skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ is a skew-symmetric matrix. Fix an elementary row operation. If we carry out this row operation on $A$, and then carry out the corresponding column operation on the resulting matrix, do we obtain a new skew-symmetric matrix?

I believe the answer is yes. I have tested it on a few skew-symmetric matrices and it seems to hold. However, I'm not sure if it generalizes to an $n\times n$ skew-symmetric matrix. Is this a commonly proved result? Where can it be found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A$ be skew-symmetric. If $E$ is an elementary matrix, then doing the row operation corresponds to multiplying on the left of $A$ by $E$, and doing the corresponding column operation corresponds to multiplying on the right by $E^T$. Hence, doing both the row operation and the column operation results in the matrix $EAE^T$. Taking the transpose of this is $(E^T)^T A^T E^T = E (-A) E^T = - EAE^T$; hence, $EAE^T$ is skew-symmetric.